# How is this [] operator overloaded?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I'm trying to construct a 2D vector class myself.

When I'm looking for sample code implemented by others, I found this:

```
class Vector2D {
 public:

  // components
  double x, y;

  Vector2D() : x( 0.0 ), y( 0.0 ) { }

  // returns reference to the specified component (0-based indexing: x, y)
  inline double& operator[] ( const int& index ) {
    return ( &x )[ index ];
  }
}
```

How is the `[]` operator overloaded? How do I understand `(&x)[index]`?

Comment: You found garbage. Change your learning material to something that [makes sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282).

Comment: I believe this example is undefined behavior. It relies on `y` being immediately after `x` in memory and I'm not certain that this is guaranteed.

Comment: `const int& index` is premature pessimism. It adds a layer of indirection with no possible gain.

Answer (score 5):

> How is the `[]` operator overloaded?

Badly.

> How do I understand `(&x)[index]`?

It's a line of code that pretends we can safely navigate around a class's members using pointer arithmetic. We can't. The code is broken.

Furthermore, taking an `int` by const reference is just stupid; there's essentially no way that's going to be of use to an optimiser. `int`s are tiny, possibly even *smaller* than the pointer that your compiler is likely to need "under the hood" to implement this reference.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that it's broken; `Vector2D` as it is is standard layout (actually, it's even POD), and the standard gives much stronger guarantees about the layout in memory for standard layout classes.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: You simply can't use pointer arithmetic to "jump" objects like this, no matter what their layout is. C++14 5.7/5 is clear that this is UB.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition that reference to the standard is important enough to be part of the answer.